# Pdf generation with PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

I was wondering does anyone know any PHP Pdf generation libraries that support absolute positioning.

I'm needing to generate pdf's dynamically, all positing needs to be done absolute.

does such a library exist, I tried domPdf it doesn't support it though :(

Comment: As far as I know, almost all libs allow so. What have you discarded already?

Comment: "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)"

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: PDF Generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938664/php-pdf-generation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend Zend_Pdf since I've run into some weird errors with larger PDF files, and I find it a bit crude to work with. Fpdf would be my choice. It's easy to learn, versitile and quite easy to integrate into Zend Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Zend_PDF is done almost entirely in absolute positioning afaik

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of a PDF template that was built in InDesign and Zend_Pdf to place the dynamic content in the file.

Answer (score 0):

In zend-framework, Zend_PDF is a good option.

Following links might help you :

http://devzone.zend.com/article/12492

http://devzone.zend.com/article/2525

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter Framework,

R&OS is a good class..

Here are the links that you can use

[Generate PDF File with values from MySQL DB using CodeIgniter Framework](http://www.code2learn.com/2012/02/generating-pdf-files-from-database.html)

[Generate tabulated PDF File with values from MySQL DB using CodeIgniter Framework](http://www.code2learn.com/2012/03/generating-tabulated-pdf-file-from.html)